# Bash Script Extract Filename from ls -l Results

Tags: linux, shell-script, ls

I have a Bash Script that is intended to locate files that are created on a specific date. It is working as bellow.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCATION="/tmp/testfiles"
DATE="Jan 10"
COMMAND="ls -l ${LOCATION} | grep '${DATE}'"

for FILE in `eval $COMMAND`
do
    echo $FILE
done
```

It is locating the file that I expect it to

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  9485 Jan 10 10:00 test01.log
```

But the bash for loop is looping through all of the fields of the ls -l command so I am ending up with

```
-rw-rw-rw-
1
root
root
9485
Jan
10
10:00
test01.log
```

Which I don't want. Is it possible to extract the filename from an ls -l command in order to keep the loop from processing all of the fields.

I can't use just ls in this case because I need to know the date in order for the grep to work.

PS. I know it's not recommended to store commands into variables but I need it like that for now, I will probably change it at a later stage.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should print all the paths of the files modified between the given dates:

```
find . -type f -newermt '2018-01-17' ! -newermt '2018-01-18'
```

that should work when used in your script provided none of the file names contain space, tab, newline and wildcard characters (and you haven't modified `$IFS`):

```
FILES=$(find /your/path -type f -newermt '2018-01-17' ! -newermt '2018-01-18')

for file in $FILES; do
    echo "${file}"
done
```

it will print the paths and not just the filenames.

depending on what you want to do with those files also consider executing the commands on the files direcly with `find -exec command`.

Comment: `find` is good. But your implementation will break when file names contain spaces. (A sufficiently common situation that it's worth covering. I'm not going to talk about other non-printables such as `\n`.)

Comment: Damn, I was afraid of that. I was avoiding this because on my linux I have to use newer which requires a file as a reference but if it's the only way then that's that. Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @Trent you've tagged with [tag:centos] so why are you constrained to `-newer` rather than `-newermt`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I couldn't get newermt to work on my system a while ago so had to use newer. I don't remember the details though

Comment: @roaima yes, you are right! depending on what the use-case is i would suggest to use `find`'s `-exec` in order to apply the command(s) to the given file...

Comment: See also: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 3):

Using  the output of any form of the `ls` command in shell scripts is almost universally highly discouraged. Even were you to use `ls -1` (that's a number, "one") instead of `ls -l`, you would have to deal with filenames containing embedded spaces, etc.

Instead, use the `find` command, with the `-print0` option for safe printing, and with the `-ctime` option for limiting to a specific file creation time.

Comment: `-ctime` is NOT file creation time. It's the time the inode was last changed. Most Linux/UNIX filesystems do not store creation time, just the date/time the file was last modified. Reference that with `-mtime`

Answer (score 2):

To perform this task safely you should not parse `ls`, and you should avoid using `eval` whenever possible. In this suggestion I've also protected the code against spaces and strange characters in the filenames:

```
date="Jan 10 2017"
find -type f -newermt "$date" \! -newermt "$date + 1 day" -printf '%P\0' |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\000' f;
    do
        echo ">> $f <<"
    done
```

If you just want to capture the filename you don't need the `while read` loop and you can also use `find ... -printf "%P"` without the trailing `\0`.